# Scale images according to device

Tags: android, image

I have developed an `Android` game using a `Canvas`. When I port the game on devices with different resolutions, the graphics, such as `ImageButton`s, get scaled according to resolution, but the background images do not scale appropriately.

I have written these lines in manifest file :

```
<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"
      />
```

Why don't the background images scale correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageView.ScaleType

ImageView.ScaleType="CENTER_CROP"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `ImageView` that will most likely scale automatically. At least it did in my program. It's worth a try.